# How to download MonkeyTalk testing tool?

Tags: testing, monkeytalk

I spent lot of time to find out a way to download monkeyTalk testing software. But I couldn't find a link to download it or event there is no sign up page or login at https://gorillalogic.com/. Need a help to download monkeyTalk software, how to configure it and sample example please.

Answer (score 8):

Seems it's in hiding until Oracle releases the product. Just received the following email from a contact at Oracle:

> Thanks for the email.
>
> Oracle Engineering Team is working on the next release. I don’t have a definite release date. Shall send an update when ready.

## ============

(previous thread)

Yeah, I've been searching all morn in hopes of updating our MT framework and I'm not finding anything.

Used to be a quick download easily found on their site. Will report back if I stumble on the downloads for Gorilla Logic. Seems they're more concerned w/ marketing themselves right now then making their software available.

This is the closest thing I could find that's still on their site, which is super old, but the link in the post just sends you back to homepage: https://gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-beta-3-adds-hybrid-nativehtml-app-scripting/

=======

Came across this after posting. Seems Oracle bought MonkeyTalk, if I'm reading it correctly: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/acquisitions/cloudmonkey/index.html

Shooting Oracle email and Gorilla Logic a tweet. Will report back if I hear anything.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the feedback. Sorry, I'm a newb and apparently don't have enough reputation to comment when I attempt that. And I thought there was a partial answer here as to the shifting nature of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is simple and free solution: browser based tool like this one: **Ripple simulator** (Beta phase) on link: [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

Answer (score 0):

Gorilla Logic no longer supports MonkeyTalk as they were sold to Oracle in 2015. http://go.gorillalogic.com/cloud-monkey-and-flex-monkey-downloads